# how to download images from fire-base store. i am using vue-firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

i store the images on firbase firestore and data on collections.
i want to retrieve the data with images on vue application but i cannot get download images URL. 
How to Download All Images from vue firestore from store section?
with relationship.
E.g
user detail are in collection folder and profile pictures are in store sections.
how to download profile picture from store sections simply write thr code in vuejs

my code for sigle preview is here:

vuejs , firestore store , vue-firestore real time

````
         const user= fb.auth().currentUser;
     return{
         Profile:db.collection("User_Profile/").doc(user.uid),


     }
 },
 methods:{

selectFile () {
     this.$refs.uploadInput.click()
   },
   detectFiles (e) {
     let fileList = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files
     Array.from(Array(fileList.length).keys()).map(x => {
       this.upload(fileList[x])
     })
   },
   upload (file) {
     this.fileName = file.name
     this.uploadTask = fb.storage().ref('UsedCar/' + file.name).put(file)
   },
   deleteImage(img,id){
       let image=fb.storage().refFromURL(img);
       this.allImages.splice(id,1);
       image.delete().then(res=>{

      Swal.fire('Deleted')
       }).catch(error=>{

       Swal.fire({
               type: 'error',
               title: 'Oops...',
               text: 'Something went wrong!',
               footer: '<a href>image Not Deleted</a>'
               })
       })

   }  
 },   
 watch: {
   uploadTask: function () {
     this.uploadTask.on('state_changed', sp => {
     },
     null,
     () => {
       this.uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
         this.allImages.push(downloadURL);

       })
     })
   }
 }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

For that you should have store link in firebase real-time database or Firestore to download using inbuilt download manager in Android 
Otherwise there is know way to download file uploaded in storage

Comment: i am using in web application not in android i am talking about vuejs,